# custom assertion to compare arrays in Nightwatch.js does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, nightwatch.js, assertions

I use `nightwatch-cucumber` that based on `Nightwatch.js` as testing framework to implement my automated end2end tests. So, I'm still new to 'JavaScript' and 'node.js'. Currently, I want to create a custom assertion in Nightwatch, but I get an error while test execution and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I get the following error:

`Testing if arrays are equal. - Expected "true" but got: "[object Object]"`

The assertion should compare different arrays in a given array, if they inherit equal values. So the array to give as parameter should like this `var myArray[[1,2,3], [3,2,1]]`. The assertion should compare all arrays in a given array with each other.

Here is my custom assertion:

```
var equals = require('array-equal');
var util = require('util');

exports.assertion = function(array, msg=null) {
    this.message = msg || util.format('Testing if arrays are equal.');
    this.expected = true;

    this.pass = function(value) {
        return value === this.expected;
    };

  this.value = function(result) {
    return result.value;
  };

    this.command = function(callback) {
        let params = [array];

      let execute = function(array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          for (var k = i+1; k < array.length; k++) {
            array[i].sort();
            array[k].sort();
            if (equals(array[i], array[k]) === false) {
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
        return true;
      };

      let execcallback = result => {
        if (callback) {
          return callback.call(this, result);
        }
      };

      return this.api.execute(execute, params, execcallback);
    };
};
```

I use the `PageObject` pattern to write my tests.

Here is my code for executing my assertion:

```
module.exports = {
  elements: {},
  commands: [{

    compareArrays() {
      var list = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]];
      //I expect a passed assertion because the values in both arrays are equal
      this.assert.arraysEqual(list);
      return this.api;
    }
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in the loops?
Why don't place just

```
array[i].sort();
array[k].sort();
if (equals(array[i], array[k]) === false) {
   return false;
}
```